# Как задать стиль вложеному элементу?

Tags: html, css

Я имею

```html
<li class="woof_term_598 ">
   <div class="icheckbox_flat-grey">
     <input type="checkbox" class="woof_checkbox_term" name="chernyj">
      <ins class="iCheck-helper">  
      </ins>
   </div>
   <label class="woof_checkbox_label " >Черный
      <span class="woof_checkbox_count">(11)</span>
   </label>
   <input type="hidden" value="Черный" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_cvet_chernyj">
</li>
```

как мне для слова Черный(11) задать `color:black`
используя  `name="chernyj"`

т.е. я могу задать цвет для этого слова например так

`.woof_checkbox_label span {color:black}`

или

`.woof_checkbox_count {color:black}`

Hо мне нужна зависимость от `name="chernyj"`(ну или от data-anchor="woof_n_pa_cvet_chernyj")
Почему это не работает

```css
.icheckbox_flat-grey input[name="chernyj"] + .woof_checkbox_label span   {
     color: black !important;
   }
```

Comment: для текущего Html - с помощью только css никак

Answer (score 0):

> Комбинатор `+` выбирает **элемент**, который находится непосредственно
>   **после** указанного элемента, если у них **общий родитель**.

```css
li {
color: red;
}

input[data-anchor$="_chernyj"] + .woof_checkbox_label  {
   color: black;
}
```

```html
<li class="woof_term_598 ">
   <div class="icheckbox_flat-grey">
     <input type="checkbox" class="woof_checkbox_term" name="chernyj">
      <ins class="iCheck-helper">  
      </ins>
   </div>
   <label class="woof_checkbox_label" >Черный
      <span class="woof_checkbox_count">(11)</span>
   </label>
   <input type="hidden" value="Черный" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_cvet_chernyj">
</li>
```

> Комбинатор `~` выбирает **элементы**, которые находятся на **этом же
>   уровне** вложенности, **после** указанного элемента, с **тем же
>   родителем**.

```css
li {
color: red;
}

input[name="chernyj"] ~ .woof_checkbox_label  {
   color: black;
}
```

```html
<li class="woof_term_598 ">
   <div class="icheckbox_flat-grey">
     <input type="checkbox" class="woof_checkbox_term" name="chernyj">
      <ins class="iCheck-helper">  
      </ins>
     <input type="hidden" value="Черный" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_cvet_chernyj">
     <label class="woof_checkbox_label" >Черный
       <span class="woof_checkbox_count">(11)</span>
     </label>
   </div> 
</li>
```

JS

```js
document.querySelector("[data-anchor=woof_n_pa_cvet_chernyj]").previousElementSibling.style.color="black";

//либо через назначение класса
//document.querySelector("[data-anchor=woof_n_pa_cvet_chernyj]").previousElementSibling.classList.add("black")
```

```css
li {
color: red;
}

.black {
color: black;
}
```

```html
<li class="woof_term_598 ">
   <div class="icheckbox_flat-grey">
     <input type="checkbox" class="woof_checkbox_term" name="chernyj">
      <ins class="iCheck-helper">  
      </ins>
   </div>
   <label class="woof_checkbox_label" >Черный
      <span class="woof_checkbox_count">(11)</span>
   </label>
   <input type="hidden" value="Черный" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_cvet_chernyj">
</li>
```

Comment: Вы изменили  html. У меня нет возможности менять html , поэтому ваш вариант не может работать

Comment: Правильней тогда сказать, что мой вариант работает, но у вас нет возможности менять html :) а что насчет JS? Добавил 2 варианта.